# How to split a DataFrame into separate groups based on a Value(Difference Value of Time)

Tags: python, pandas, split, slice, data-analysis

I'm now using Pandas in Python to handle some data.

Simplified DataFrame is

[ID, TimeDiff] and some other not-important columns.

For example:

```
73    1.166667
74    1.166667
75    2.183333
76    3.466667
77    2.666667
78    Na
```

TimeDiff means the difference value of time in data ID. 3.466667 means the time between ID 76 and ID 77 is 3.466667 hours.
I want to split vessel data to make sure the difference value of time is within 2 hours
so I need to split DataFrame into N different groups (in this example, N = 4).

I need to get results like this: whenever TimeDiff >= 2 create another group

```
--------------
73    1.166667
74    1.166667
-------------
75    2.183333
--------------
76    3.466667
--------------
77         NaN
```

I have tried to use Groupby in pandas.

```py
df.groupby('TimeDiff')
```

But obviously, this is not what I want.
I'm now trying to split DataFrame step by step like this:
From

```
73    1.166667
74    1.166667
--------------
75    2.183333
76    3.466667
77    2.666667
78    Na
```

To

```
73    1.166667
74    1.166667
--------------
75    2.183333
--------------
76    3.466667
77    2.666667
78    Na
```

Then To

```
73    1.166667
74    1.166667
--------------
75    2.183333
--------------
76    3.466667
77    2.666667
78    Na
```

......

Finally to what I want:

```
--------------
73    1.166667
74    1.166667
-------------
75    2.183333
--------------
76    3.466667
--------------
77         NaN
```

4 groups Data. But after searching Google and StackOverflow I didn't find a proper way to handle it. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` to create your groups:

```
df['Group'] = df['TimeDiff'].fillna(np.inf).ge(2).cumsum()
print(df)

# Output
   ID  TimeDiff  Group
0  73  1.166667      0
1  74  1.166667      0
2  75  2.183333      1
3  76  3.466667      2
4  77  2.666667      3
5  78       NaN      4
```

Using `groupby`:

```
>>> list(df.groupby(df['TimeDiff'].fillna(np.inf).ge(2).cumsum()))
[(0,
     ID  TimeDiff  Group
  0  73  1.166667      0
  1  74  1.166667      0),

 (1,
     ID  TimeDiff  Group
  2  75  2.183333      1),

 (2,
     ID  TimeDiff  Group
  3  76  3.466667      2),

 (3,
     ID  TimeDiff  Group
  4  77  2.666667      3),

 (4,
     ID  TimeDiff  Group
  5  78       NaN      4)]
```